# Peer to peer lending business model (i.e. Lending Club)

Tags: peer-to-peer-lending, legal, lending-club, microlending

I am doing some research on the peer-to-peer business model.

When looking at [Lending Club](https://www.lendingclub.com/), I was wondering what the legal framework model is for them.

To be more specific, how are they set up as a company? How do they manage the lenders' money and how do they interact for loan repayment, commissions, etc...? How is the lender's money transferred to the borrower? I guess not through the Lending Club company, for reasons of risk.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about not directly related to personal finance

Comment: I can see this being on topic.  It is important to know how something like peer to peer works before lending or borrowing from it.  Banks processes are understood at a basic level so we can trust them, therefore understanding peer to peer is just as important as personal user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is all answered in the [prospectus](https://www.lendingclub.com/fileDownload.action?file=Clean_As_Filed_20130430.pdf&type=docs).

The money not yet invested (available/committed to a note but not yet funded) is held in pooled trust account insured by FDIC.

Money funded is delivered to the borrower.

Lending Club service their notes themselves.

Read also [my reviews on Lending Club](http://littleadvisor.wordpress.com/tag/lending-club/).

Comment: Thanks, I was also hoping to find a graph with the different parties involved (i.e. Lender, Borrower, Trust, Lending Club) and the flows

Comment: @samyb8 not surprisingly, you can find that in the prospectus as well. See page 6 (page 10 of the PDF).

Comment: +1 @littleadv for doing his homework for him.  He will probably get a good grade.

Comment: If the homework was to force him read the prospectus, then I think the mission has been accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

The best description of P2P lending process I saw comes from the SEC proceedings. They are very careful about naming things that are happening in the process.

### Prosper Cease-and-Desist

- https://www.sec.gov/litigation/admin/2008/33-8984.pdf

Prosper got back to business after this order, but the paper describes succinctly how Prosper worked when its notes haven't yet been registered by the SEC.

### SEC Proceedings

- Crowdfunding And The Federal Securities Laws http://www.sec.gov/info/smallbus/acsec/bradford_crowdfunding.pdf https://www.sec.gov/rules/proposed/2013/33-9470.pdf
- Comments on Proposed Rule: Crowdfunding https://www.sec.gov/comments/s7-09-13/s70913.shtml

These materials contain a lot of responsible comments on how crowdfunding, including P2P lending, works.